# Поиск индекса значения из последовательности Фибоначчи

Tags: prolog, числа-фибоначчи, gnu-prolog

Здравствуйте, написал поиск значения из посл-ти Фибоначчи по индексу. Встала обратная задача. Вроде работает рекурсивный алгоритм, поставил write() и видно что программа выходит из рекурсии когда находит индекс, но проблема в том, что я не могу найденный индекс вернуть.

```
predicates
fib2(integer, integer)
fibm(integer, integer, integer)

clauses
    fib2(1,1) :- !.
    fib2(2,1) :- !.
    fib2(N,F) :-
        N1 = N - 1,
        fib2(N1,F1),
        N2 = N-2,
        fib2(N2,F2),
        F = F1+F2.

    fibm(1, 1, 1) :- !.
    fibm(2, 1, 1) :- !.
    fibm(X, N1, Q) :-
        R = N1 + 1,
        fib2(R, T),
        write("    R = ",R),
        T < X,              
        fibm(X, R),
        Q = R.


goal
fibm(21, 0, Q).
```

На вход подается значение из последовательности и нужно вернуть индекс этого значения.

Comment: В предпоследней цели ошибка: дожно быть `fibm/3` или `fib/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал запустить Ваш код, поправив его под SWI-Prolog. В остальном оставил примерно всё как есть:

```
    fib2( 1 ,1 ) :- !.
    fib2( 2 ,1 ) :- !.
    fib2( N ,F ) :-
        N1 is N - 1,
        fib2( N1, F1 ),
        N2 is N - 2,
        fib2( N2, F2 ),
        F is F1 + F2.

    fibm( 1, 1, 1 ) :- !.
    fibm( 2, 1, 1 ) :- !.
    fibm( X, N1, Q ) :-
        R is N1 + 1,
        fib2( R, T ),
        writef('    R = %w',[ R ]),
        T < X,      
        R = Q,         
        fibm( X, R ).

%%%    
goal :-
    fibm( 21, 0, Q ), writef('\nQ = %w', [ Q ] ).

qoal :-  
    write('no ( more ) solutions.').

:- initialization( goal ).
```

Запустил, получил результат:

R = 1

**ERROR**: c:/downloads/fib_c.pl:27: Initialization goal raised exception:

**ERROR:** fibm/3: Undefined procedure: fibm/2

**ERROR:**   However, there are definitions for:

**ERROR:**         fib2/2

**ERROR:**         fibm/3

true.

Я подправил код и получил такой результат:

```
    fib2( 1 ,1 ) :- !.
    fib2( 2 ,1 ) :- !.
    fib2( N ,F ) :-
        N1 is N - 1,
        fib2( N1, F1 ),
        N2 is N - 2,
        fib2( N2, F2 ),
        F is F1 + F2.

    fibm( 1, 1, 1 ) :- !.
    fibm( 2, 1, 1 ) :- !.
    fibm( X, N1, Q ) :-
        R is N1 + 1,
        fib2( R, T ),
        writef('    R = %w',[ R ]),
        T < X,      
        R = Q,         
        fibm( X, R, Q ).

%%%    
goal :-
    fibm( 21, 0, Q ), writef('\nQ = %w', [ Q ] ).

qoal :-  
    write('no ( more ) solutions.').

:- initialization( goal ).
```

R = 1    R = 2

Warning: c:/downloads/fib_c.pl:27: Initialization goal failed

true.

Надеюсь, смог Вам помочь.

Answer (score -1):

Числа Фибоначчи асимптотически равны 1.6180339887498948482**(n-1)
потому если вы сделаете над значением некоторого: `1+ Math.ceil(Math.log(x)/0.48121182505960347)` - вы получите его индекс
(конечно без проверки, что это реально является числом Фибоначчи, потому что это аппроксимация. Но вы не уточняли что конкретно вы проверяете, потому привожу этот быстрый способ)

```js
//test in browser console
const LOG_FI = Math.log(1.6180339887498948482);
const logFi=(x)=>Math.log(x)/LOG_FI; //0.48121182505960347
const guess=(x)=>Math.ceil(logFi(x))+1;
for(let x=0,next=1, i=0; i<10; [x,next]=[next,x+next],i++){
    console.log({i,x,guess:guess(x),log:logFi(x)})
}
```

#### Производительность:

Не сказать что бы логарифм был приятной по скорости функцией, однако аналитический метод быстро переплюнет рекурсию, при сколь-нибудь большом значении числа.

#### Ограничения:

- Для нуля логарифм не определен (-Infifnity)
- Для 1,2 членов возвратит 1 (т.к. их значения не отличаются)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy